# VotingApi / Fivestar rating Player per Game

Tags: rating

Can not figure how this works, and hope is doable.

I'd like to add a feature using the fivestar module but I could not figure it out myself. The work may simply require configuring the module correctly or make code changes.

1. I create a new node with "game" content type for each game.
2. I add the team squad (list of players) for that game. Each player is a separate node, with "player" content type.
3. I would like each player to be voted per game and display the score of the player for that game only. This is where I'm stuck, I could not display player votes per game.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an intermediary content type containing two reference fields and a fivestar field. One reference field references the game, the other references the player. Then use views as a block with a contextual filter to display the fivestar and the player info on the game node.